# Creating attribute sets and attributes programmatically

Tags: magento, attributes

I am using the code listed on the following link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets

Everything works until the point:

```
    // Just add a default group.
    else
    {
        $this->logInfo("Creating default group [{$this->groupName}] for set.");

        $modelGroup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group');
        $modelGroup->setAttributeGroupName($this->groupName);
        $modelGroup->setAttributeSetId($id);

        // This is optional, and just a sorting index in the case of
        // multiple groups.
        // $modelGroup->setSortOrder(1);

        $model->setGroups(array($modelGroup));
    }
```

I am unsure where the object reference would need to be set from - I am attempting to have this as a separate file that can be automated - I am running this file by doing a

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app();
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Instead of logInfo, you should you Mage::log().

Comment: Thanks Vern - will do that - I am referring to the $this->groupName which doesn't return anything - using it as a separate script, how do I instantiate this object in order to get and set the group name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to have a block in your modules config.xml that looks like so

```
<resources>
    <namespace_module_setup><!-- becomes folder under sql dir -->
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </namespace_module_setup>
</resources>
```

This will allow you to place your installer code in the directory that is in your XML.  You need to make sure that the version listed on the installer file matches the `<version>1.2.0</version>` of your module otherwise Magento will not be able to run your installer.  To add an attribute Set, you can use the following data, I have never use it, but the entityTypeId defines whether it is a customer, shipping, category, product entity, each 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively.

```
/**
     * Add Attribute Set
     *
     * @param mixed $entityTypeId
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
     */
    public function addAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $name, $sortOrder = null)
    {
        $data = array(
            'entity_type_id'        => $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId),
            'attribute_set_name'    => $name,
            'sort_order'            => $this->getAttributeSetSortOrder($entityTypeId, $sortOrder),
        );

        $setId = $this->getAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $name, 'attribute_set_id');
        if ($setId) {
            $this->updateAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $setId, $data);
        } else {
            $this->_conn->insert($this->getTable('eav/attribute_set'), $data);

            $this->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $name, $this->_generalGroupName);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

This is the code for adding an attribute to a set, just change the attribute set data

```
//app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/Namespace_Module_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
    $installer = $this;
    /* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

    $installer->startSetup();

        $data= array (
            'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
            'group' => 'General',
            'label'    => 'Some Label',
            'visible'     => true,
            'type'     => 'varchar', // multiselect uses comma-sep storage
            'input'    => 'text',
            'system'   => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1, //defaults to false; if true, define a group
        );

        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','attriute_code',$data)

        $installer->endSetup();
```

The above is a working example of an attribute installation for a module.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier one-liner for this. Just extend Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup for your install script and use something like this in your installer:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttributeSet(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'New Attribute Set Name');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this as an installer, so Magento loads it when the module is installed (or upgraded). `$this`, in the example, means that installer class.

You could create the module and the installer using https://bitbucket.org/alexsiri7/qbmagemoduleshell, and then adding that code there. That tool is a module creator I developed.