# Magento : How to add attributes using install/upgrade script?

Tags: magento

I want to know how to add a Magento EAV attributes to an existing group programmatically.

Can anyone share some information for adding attributes using install or upgrade script?

I have followed some tutorials but no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Souf,there are lot of code,are available 
here some link is below

```
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147847/creating-attribute-sets-and-attributes-programmatically][1]
[http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets][1]
```

Some upgrade of attribute

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'price_view', 'used_in_product_listing', 1);
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'shipment_type', 'used_in_product_listing', 1);
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'weight_type', 'used_in_product_listing', 1);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: this is my question i used this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409317/magento-adding-attribut-using-install-script is it wrong ?